# List View Threshold - Date Filter

Tags: list, list-view, list-view-threshold

We have a list with ~6000 items and an indexed column `Date Created`.

There are two filtered views:

Items Younger Than 30 Days
Filter: `Greater Than [Today] - 30`
This view works correctly.

Items Older Than 30 Days 
Filter: `Less Than or Equal [Today] - 30`
**This view throws a list threshold error.**

About half of the items were created before last month.

Can someone please help me identify the reason why "Younger" works and "Older" fails?

Edit:

One hypothesis is that the Less Than query may not be not SARGable in the way that the Greater Than query is (see below link). If SP is attempting to evaluate all 6k rows, not just the bottom 3k, perhaps that pushes us beyond the limit. [reference](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/01/19/sargable-expression-performance/)

Comment: but are they more than 30 days old?

Comment: Fair question. Yes - there are about 3k items over 30 days and 3k items below 30 days. We archive older items that are "completed" to a separate list, and selected 30 days as an appropriate cutoff that would always be about 50% of the total.

Comment: In the filtered view for older items, are you sorting from oldest to newest?

Comment: Yes - there is a sort - first on `Date` and then on a `Status` field (also indexed). Identical filters on both filtered lists. No effect when we remove the Sort (or reverse the Sort order).